# Logs for failed Docker build

Tags: node.js, docker, node-modules, docker-build

I have a simple nodejs app. While trying to load the libraries i used `npm link library1 library2` which created symlinks to */usr/local/lib/node_modules*. I am trying to build the docker image of the same using following instructions in my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13-alpine
ENV MONGO_DB_USERNAME=admin \
    MONGO_DB_PWD=password
RUN mkdir -p /home/app 
COPY ./app /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Now while building the image it errored out `RUN npm install` section with following output in the terminal

```
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /home/app/node_modules/body-parser
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/home/app/node_modules/body-parser'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-23T21_41_24_539Z-debug.log
```

I was successfully able to build the image after removing the node_modules folder in my code location. Also i was successfully able to build the image when i downloaded the libraries via `npm install libary1 library2` in the code location.

My questions are

1. Why is the image build process erroring out when i use the global libaries
2. Where can i find the logs file indicated in the terminal. My local laptop doesn't have /root/ folder.

Comment: Can you please provide your full Dockerfile or at least what base image(s) it's from? Also the npm error is saying the log is in the `/root` folder inside the Docker container do you'd need to access the container through a shell or copying the file (using Docker's `exec` or `cp` command.

Comment: apologies for missing out on the complete Dockerfile. updated it. Which container i would need to exec into to get the logs. I noticed that few temporary containers were started and stoped(rather than deleted for case when the image build is successful). I tried to restart the stopped container but it would stop within a minutes, not giving me change to exec

Comment: How are you trying to start the stopped container? Are you using a command such as `docker run -it CONTAINER bash`? This error seems to be related to npm package files but this might help getting those logs.

Comment: I am not sure if you meant docker run or docker exec. But I got the container id using 'docker ps -a' then using then 'docker start <container_id>' and 'docker exec -it <container_id> bash'. the docker exec would exit in a minute because the temp container,which was created for building image, would stop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker containers have isolated filesystems from the host and from other containers.  `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` in a container is completely different from the same directory on the host, and similarly, `/root` on the host is separate from `/root` in any given container.  That's why the image build can't use the host-global modules, and why you're having trouble reading the detailed logs.

As far as the Dockerfile goes, the important thing is to make sure the `package.json` file is complete.  `npm link` won't work; make sure you `npm install body-parser` and any other modules you need, and that all of the dependencies are listed out in `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

The host's `node_modules` tree can be different from the image's in several ways (most notably if you're using a Linux container on a non-Linux host).  You can avoid problems here, and speed up the build, by making sure `node_modules` is listed in a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) in the same directory as the Dockerfile.

You say deleting the host's `node_modules` directory fixes the build, so excluding it from the `docker build` context will likely fix it as well.

---

If that doesn't work and you still want to see the logs, you can get a shell in a container based on the partial build, up to the last successful step.  Say the output of `docker build` is

```
Step 5/7 : WORKDIR /home/app
 ---> 123456789abc
Step 6/7 : RUN npm install
 ... the error text you quoted ...
```

That hex number is a valid Docker image ID, so you can manually repeat the last (failing) step, starting from the results of the previous (successful) step.  Run:

```
host$ sudo docker run --rm -it 123456789abc sh
13579bdf2468# npm install
...
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-23T21_41_24_539Z-debug.log
13579bdf2468# cat /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-23T21_41_24_539Z-debug.log
```

(Very recent versions of Docker have [a different build engine](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) and somewhat different output.  You may need to add `--progress=plain` to get more information out.)

Comment: Thank you for clarification on error and steps on how to login into container based on paritial build. But there is no directory with name .npm in /root directory. i actually ran `ls alR | grep "<filename>"` but it gave no output. Just to be sure i also did `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty` and checked for logs in /root/.npm still not directory or file. Am i missing anything? I mean i know why is the error this time so i can let of logs but in case of future error i want to understand where are the logs located.

Comment: I clarified the answer a little bit: you need to re-run the last step, by hand, in an interactive shell, starting from the last successful step.  Once the `RUN` step fails, all of its outputs are gone.  (It will not be on the host or in the hidden Linux VM anywhere.)  (IME you don't usually need this log and the `ENOENT` error Node is already printing out is enough information.)

Comment: It works and i am able to replicate the error and log. Thank you.